# How can I make a Docker healthcheck with wget instead of curl?

Tags: docker, wget

Docker [healthcheck document](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck) shows this for curl:

```
HEALTHCHECK --interval=5m --timeout=3s \
  CMD curl -f http://localhost/ || exit 1
```

I want a one-line equivalent in wget that would exit 1 when HTTP 200 is not returned.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

The following seems to be the equivalent:

```
HEALTHCHECK  --interval=5m --timeout=3s \
  CMD wget --no-verbose --tries=1 --spider http://localhost/ || exit 1
```

Where:

- `--no-verbose` - Turn off verbose without being completely quiet (use -q for that), which means that error messages and basic information still get printed.
- `--tries=1` - If not set, some wget implementations will retry indefinitely when HTTP 200 response is not returned.
- `--spider` - Behave as a Web spider, which means that it will not download the pages, just check that they are there.
- `exit 1` - Ensures exit code 1 on failure. Heathcheck only expects the following:

  - 0: success - the container is healthy and ready for use
  - 1: unhealthy - the container is not working correctly
  - 2: reserved - do not use this exit code

Docker compose example:

```yaml
healthcheck:
   test: wget --no-verbose --tries=1 --spider http://localhost || exit 1
   interval: 5m
   timeout: 3s
   retries: 3
   start_period: 2m
```

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#healthcheck

Comment: Why the `|| exit 1` ?  If wget fails, the health check will fail anyway

Comment: Is there any workaround way to stop the docker container, if the HEALTHCHECK status is unhealthy. I mean, with the docker file, is this possible to stop the docker container based on the HEALTHCHECK status code.

Comment: Sorry for the necropost, but I'm linux-impaired; what's the advantage of using wget instead of curl in this case?

Comment: @J.ScottElblein most times it's dependent on what's available in the container.  `wget` may be available and `curl` may not, or vice versa.

Comment: how on earth do you do a `|| exit 1` in docker compose?

Comment: @Peter: this is actually given as an example in the [official docker compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#healthcheck) and the reason for this has been given in comment by OP above but you can also check the [Dockerfile reference documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck) for more information.

Comment: this is making a head request. Thats not equivalent.

Answer (score 10):

Dennis Hoer's answer is great, but I prefer `-nv` (`--no-verbose`) instead of `--quiet`, then if an error occurs, the reason is available from Docker:

```
HEALTHCHECK --interval=5s --timeout=5s --retries=3 \
    CMD wget -nv -t1 --spider 'http://localhost:8000/' || exit 1
```

Example output captured by Docker:

```
% docker inspect $container --format "{{ (index (.State.Health.Log) 0).Output }}"
Connecting to localhost:8000 (127.0.0.1:8000)
wget: server returned error: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

Comment: That is a good suggestion, too bad alpine wget doesn't support that flag.

Comment: @DennisHoer Works for me all the way back to Alpine 3.9, I tried running `docker run -it alpine:3.9 wget -nv -t1 --spider 'http://localhost:8000/'`

Comment: Good to know, because it is not in the help page.  Updated answer to use --no-verbose. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

i have another solution to that problem:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 3<>/dev/tcp/localhost/"$1"

echo -e "GET /path/to/health/endpoint/ HTTP/1.1
host: localhost:$1
" >&3

timeout 1 cat <&3 | grep status | grep UP || exit 1
```

use this script in your compose.yaml

```
healthcheck:
  test: [ 'CMD-SHELL', '/bin/bash -c "/path/to/healthcheck.sh 8081"' ]
  ...
```

i have summarized why this works here:

https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-docker/issues/58

Comment: doesn't work for me (`sh: can't create /dev/tcp/localhost/3000: nonexistent directory`) but the `/dev/tcp` trick in general seems awesome, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a `GET` request and print to standout do

```
wget -qO - http:/localhost/
```

It tells wget to be quiet `-q` and write to stdout `-O -`.

```yaml
healthcheck:
  test: wget -qO - localhost || exit 1
```

Note that the other solution, using `--spider`, makes a `HEAD` request.

Answer (score 0):

I personally met the situation when `wget` with `--spider` option didn't work but `wget` without it worked well because the tested server answered differently to these requests.

As some person has stated here

`wget ...` sends `GET` request

but

`wget --spider ...` sends `HEAD` request

and sometimes it really matters!

So I came up to the following solution:

```
wget --no-verbose --tries=1 --output-document=/dev/null http://0.0.0.0:8025/ || exit 1
```

`wget` here loads data (bad) but works for wider number of servers (good).

**UPDATE:**

If there is a risk that wget outputs some text (not only returns exit code but outputs text message in spite of `--no-verbose`) than you need to suppress it by `&> /dev/null`. If you don't do that then part `|| exit 1` doesn't work. So command should look like

```
wget --no-verbose --tries=1 --output-document=/dev/null http://0.0.0.0:8025/ &> /dev/null || exit 1
```